# Distribution of balls into boxes.

Tags: permutations, combinations, permutation-cycles

I came upon this questions on one of my tests, and wasn't able to solve it. Was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Let **m** be the number of ways 3 *identical* balls can be put into 3 *identical* boxes.

Let **n** be the number of ways 3 *different* balls can be put into 3 *identical* boxes.

Let **p** be the number of ways 3 *different* balls can be put into 3 *different boxes*.

And let **k** denote the number of ways 3 *identical* balls can be put into 3 *different* boxes.

***What is the value of m+n+p+k?***

Is there a formula for this or is it concept based?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way

Comment: Each of the four individual questions are classical examples that you should have seen solved before, or if you haven't then the fact that you have only three balls and boxes you should be able to brute force the count easily enough.  For example, with identical balls and identical boxes, you should be able to see that there are only three possibilities: three balls in one box, two balls in one and one ball in another, or one ball in each box.